# redirect IE to Edge can only do one time?

Tags: javascript, angular, internet-explorer, browser, microsoft-edge

I am trying to redirect IE users to Edge since IE is retiring.

My website is built by Angular 7 and I put this code in `ngOnInit()`

```js
const ua = window.navigator.userAgent;

if (ua.indexOf("MSIE ") > 0 || ua.indexOf("Trident") > 0) {
    window.location.href = "microsoft-edge:" + window.location.href;

    setTimeout(function () {
        window.location.href = "https://support.microsoft.com/zh-tw/office/%E9%80%99%E5%80%8B%E7%B6%B2%E7%AB%99%E5%9C%A8-internet-explorer-%E4%B8%AD%E7%84%A1%E6%B3%95%E4%BD%BF%E7%94%A8-8f5fc675-cd47-414c-9535-12821ddfc554";
    }, 0);
}
```

My steps:

1. Open IE and type `http://localhost:4200/index` into the URL bar

   → IE window: redirect to Microsoft support page

   → new Edge window open with `http://localhost:4200/index`
2. Close Edge window and keep IE window open and retype `http://localhost:4200/index` into IE

   → IE window: redirect to Microsoft support page

   → **no Edge window open**

But if I close both IE window and Edge window and open a new IE window and do the whole thing again, it works fine.

**Version Info**

- **IE version:** 1903
- **Edge version**: 98.0.1108.62

Does anyone know why and how can I fix it?

Comment: I can't reproduce the issue. It can always redirect from IE to Edge. In which file do you put the code? I suggest that you can open F12 devtools to check if there is any error in console when it doesn't work in IE. Besides, you can add breakpoints in your redirect code to see if it executes the code and what happens actually.